# how to configure windows phone to receive wns push notification

Tags: windows-phone-8, push-notification

i have developed application and need to upload beta version. in my application need to set Package SID,Application identity,Client ID,Client secret 
following warning when submitting app
"Missing certificate for authenticated push notifications: Certificate for authenticated push notifications"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i have developed application and need to upload beta version. in my application need to set Package SID,Application identity,Client ID,Client secret

I'm not sure what exactly you are talking about.
Please be more specific and detailed about what do you require help with.

All that I understand is that you want to implement Push Notification in Windows Phone.

For that, have a look at the following article.
It also has a web project that can serve as a push notification server.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh202967%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Comment: following warning occurs when submitting app "Missing certificate for authenticated push notifications: Certificate for authenticated push notifications"

Comment: that is just a warning. You don't have a push notification service certified by microsoft. you won't be able to send more than 500 notifications to a single device in a day. It would still work upto 500 notifications per device. Try by publishing it as beta.